# Where's JUnit test results located in Gradle build for Android?

Tags: android, junit, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying doing to do a continuous integration via jenkins.
I'm at the publishing tests results part now and having a bit of struggle.

> Recording test results
>   ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver aborted due to exception
>   hudson.AbortException: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:116)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:92)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:981)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:959)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser.parseResult(JUnitParser.java:89)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.parse(JUnitResultArchiver.java:121)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.perform(JUnitResultArchiver.java:138)
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:74)
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
>       at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1784)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)

It says that it cannot find any test results.

Here's path that I've set in the jenkins:
[image]

I just followed what's stated here [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-tests)

> All test results are stored as XML files under
>   build/androidTest-results

So what's the real path? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test reports path was changed since that article was written. Now you will find you reports in `<module-name>/build/outputs/reports/androidTests` directory. By default Android Studio will create module with name `app`. In that case path to your reports will be `app/build/outputs/reports/androidTests`.

Comment: Do I need to add something in my build.gradle file to tell it to output results?

Comment: No, test reports are generated every time you run your tests. I'm not that familiar with Jenkins, but you should make sure that current directory is in fact your project. For example you may need to add `<yourproject>/app/...` to the path.

Comment: I tried running my tests using android studio. I can't see any 'outputs' folder inside app/build/ Am I missing something?

Comment: Hm, that is strange. Android Studio will hide `output` folder tho. So make sure you check it in terminal or some kind of file explorer.

Comment: Did they change it again?

Comment: Yeah they did. It is now under `<module-name>/build/reports/androidTests`

Comment: It's not visible in AS, so you have to go to the folder using windows explorer.

Comment: If it's not visible in Android Studio, change the Project view window from 'Android' to 'Project'